# How to substrate number from the sum of columns of a table based on the id

Tags: mysql, sql, jpa

I have a table named deposit, below

| dep_id | deposit_amount | comp_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 1 |
| 2 | 100 | 1 |
| 3 | 100 | 1 |

When I run the query below I get the next updated table which is not what I want :

```
query = em.createNativeQuery("UPDATE deposit SET deposit_amount = (SELECT SUM(deposit_amount) - 50) WHERE comp_id = :comp_id");

query.setParameter("comp_id", comp_id);
```

The updated table after the above query

| dep_id | deposit_amount | comp_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 1 |
| 2 | 50 | 1 |
| 3 | 50 | 1 |

But I want when I substract 50 or any amount it should get the sum of the columns and minus the amount from the sum not from each column. Below

| dep_id | deposit_amount | comp_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 83.3 | 1 |
| 2 | 83.3 | 1 |
| 3 | 83.3 | 1 |

Because the sum is 300, and 300-50 = 250

Please how should I do this?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using MySQL

Answer (score 1):

You should compute deposit amount in a separate query, then join back your two tables on matching "*comp_id*" value

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT comp_id,
                    SUM(deposit_amount) OVER(PARTITION BY comp_id) AS amount
    FROM deposit
)
UPDATE deposit
INNER JOIN cte
        ON deposit.comp_id = cte.comp_id
SET deposit_amount = cte.amount - 50
WHERE deposit.comp_id = :comp_id;
```

In your final query it should look like:

```
query = em.createNativeQuery("WITH cte AS (SELECT DISTINCT comp_id, SUM(deposit_amount) OVER(PARTITION BY comp_id) AS amount FROM deposit) UPDATE deposit INNER JOIN cte ON deposit.comp_id = cte.comp_id SET deposit_amount = cte.amount - 50 WHERE deposit.comp_id = :comp_id");

query.setParameter("comp_id", comp_id);
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mBCYsZwHueHW8p7eSZnctH/0).

Answer (score 0):

Using a common table expression, you can use this query.  Get the total deposit amount per comp_id.  Then join this new table (called total) to deposit on comp_id.  Subtract 50 from the sum.

```
WITH total as(
select  comp_id, 
        sum(deposit_amount) as total
from 
        deposit 
group by 
        comp_id
  )
select dep.dep_id, 
       ttl.total - 50 as deposit_amount, 
       dep.comp_id
from
    deposit dep
inner join
    total  ttl
on 
   dep.comp_id = ttl.comp_id
```

Sample:

| dep_id | deposit_amount | comp_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 250 | 1 |
| 2 | 250 | 1 |
| 3 | 250 | 1 |